# How to serve static files on multiple endpoints?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-staticfiles

I'm serving 2 React apps with single python backend. Right now I serve `index.html` with HttpsREsponse and I have included `build/static` in STATICFILES_DIRS. Because those files have their hash prepended, they can be mixed up. But I need a way to serve all those files inside `build` like `manifes.json` or `favicon.ico`. Creating a `View` for all of them seems like a terrible idea. I would love to serve `app1/build` as `static/app1` and `app2/build` as `static/app2`.

I have searched the Django docs and have found just how to collect static from multiple locations and anything about hosting them at multiple URLs.

This is my setup right now:

```py
# settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(APP1_DIR, 'build', 'static'),
    os.path.join(APP2_DIR, 'build', 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app1/manifest.json$', getStaticFileView(app='app1', 'manifest.json').as_view()),
    url(r'^app1', getStaticFileView(app='app1', 'index.html').as_view()),
    url(r'^app2/manifest.json$', getStaticFileView(app='app2', 'manifest.json').as_view()),
    url(r'^app2', getStaticFileView(app='app2', 'index.html').as_view()),
]
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```py
# settings.py
STATICFILES_MAPPING = [
    (os.path.join(APP1_DIR, 'build', 'static'), 'static/app1'),
    (os.path.join(APP2_DIR, 'build', 'static'), 'static/app2')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app1', getStaticFileView(app='app1', 'index.html').as_view()),
    url(r'^app2', getStaticFileView(app='app2', 'index.html').as_view()),
]
```

Thanks for any ideas or directions.

Edit: I serve all static files from `/static` with static server but  I need to tell django to create correct `/static` files structure. Not to just throw everything in the `/static` folder but to put something in `/static/app1` and something in `/static/app2`

Comment: You should use an external service to serve static files, django is not designed as a static file server; see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) for information on how to setup static file serving for production.

Answer (score 0):

After Burhan Khalid's comment, I took a look at my static server and decided to serve those files right from the `/build` directory, without copying them to `/static` and serving them from there.